# create a clickable button with css2drenderer and make dynamic size depend on camera distance

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, webgl

I have two problem with using css2drenderer!

1_ I can't set click event listener on any element inside the css2drenderer! but it's work in css3drenderer! I don't want to use  css3drenderer because the object isn't face to the user!

2_ Size of the element that create with css2drenderer is not dynamic depend on distance and always have a same size! i want to change the size when I zoom in and zoom out.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question

Comment: there is an example:
https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label
I want this label be a button, I can create a button but it's not clickable!
and try to zoom in and zoom out, the size of object will change but the label not change, and I want it's change too.